# Calculate an Average with Cursor in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Homework assignment question here. Using ORACLE SQL Developer:

I have one table, employees, where it lists an employee's ID, name, department, and salary.  I need to create a PL SQL Block using an IF ELSE statement where if an employee's salary is above $5000, leave it as is.  If it is below $5000, change it to $5000 when calculating the average (not changing the data in the actual table).

I am able to get the output to show the proper values for the salary, but I am lost on how to be able to calculate the average from these values?

Here is my code to get the proper values.  I realize a CASE statement would be much easier, but we have to use an IF/ELSE statement.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cemp IS
        SELECT salary
        FROM employees WHERE department_ID = 60;
        sal employees.salary%type;
BEGIN
    OPEN cemp;
    LOOP
        FETCH cemp INTO sal;
        EXIT WHEN cemp%NOTFOUND; 
        IF sal > 5000 THEN
            sal := sal;
            UPDATE employees
            SET salary = sal;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sal);
        ELSE
            sal := 5000;
        UPDATE employees
            SET salary = sal;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sal);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    ROLLBACK;
    CLOSE cemp;
END;
```

With the above, my output, which shows the correct values, is

```
9000
6000
5000
5000
5000
```

How do I take these values and return the average in the DBMS output?

Comment: Have to use IF/ELSE as stated. The original question gives us a CASE statement and we have to convert it to IF/ELSE with a cursor.

Comment: The instructions were specifically to "change the salary" only for the purpose of computing this (fictitious) average, and **not** to change the actual salaries in the table. So, regardless of anything else, why do you have any `update` statements in the code **at all**? They will do exactly what you were explicitly asked **not** to do.

Comment: @mathguy apologies, should I then use a temp table for this to avoid that?

Comment: Despite your tutorial requirements, here some best practices: 1) if you do not want to update the database **do not** `update` and `rollback`. 2) if you need to `update` **use the WHERE** predicate (otherwise you'll update the whole table) 3) most important, if you can solve the task with *plain SQL*  use it and get rid of PL/SQL cursors. You may calculate the AVG with a simple SQL query, you may use `greatest` is you *can't* use the `case` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must go through the rows one by one, in a loop, you will need to keep two variables  - one for the running total of "salaries" and the other for the count. So - in pseudo code, since I'm not going to do your homework for you:

```
declare
   your cursor;
   total_sal number := 0;
   cnt       number := 0
begin
   for each row in the cursor
        cnt := cnt + 1;
        if salary >= 5000 then total_sal := total_sal + salary;
                          else total_sal := total_sal + 5000;
        end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('Average is: ' || to_char(total_sal / cnt));
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a 1) **PL/SQL** block, that uses 2) **IF ELSE** and performs the required taks.

Note that you may even *ommit* the `IF ELSE` statement, I added it only because it was required.

```
DECLARE
  sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF true THEN    
    select avg(greatest(salary,5000)) into sal
    from employees;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AVG salary after upgrade ' || round(sal,2));
  ELSE
    null;
  END IF;
END;
/

AVG salary after upgrade 6000
```

The point is, if you can perform an update or report with *pure SQL* - do it. You will get a sky better performance than with the *cursor row by row* solution

If your tutor will have some comments on this solution, simple ask him / her to make a *performance comparison* on a table with say 1M employees.

Comment: Did you read the question? Part of the requirement was specifically **not** to change anything in the base table; using 5000 instead of "salary" when the salary is less than 5000 was only for the purpose of computing this average - see the end of the second paragraph in the original question. So, why do you have an `update` statement in your code? I pointed this out to the OP in a comment under his question long before you posted your answer - did you miss that?

Comment: Regarding your performance comment - no doubt a direct `select` will work faster. (Another one, on the *existing* data, using a `case` expression, would be much faster still). That is very likely irrelevant; I assume the OP is learning PL/SQL, and the homework objective was to practice writing loops that do "something" (even if in this problem the "something" is trivial) and if-then-else statement structure, to understand how PL/SQL code works. A simple `select` query, while much faster, will not meet this objective.

Comment: Correct.  I realize I can use a SQL query without cursors, or using a simple `CASE` statement would be much faster, however I have to use a cursor and `IF/ELSE`.